What is this movie with an episode about presents for wedding anniversary?
I presume, this was a serial that I watched around 7 years ago, but the time I remember very vaguely. 
A couple had a wedding anniversary, and they got a lot of useless presents. One of them was a divided plate for potato chips -- two of them, to be honest, and the protagonist went to the shop to try to return one of them, because he would not need two. He described the purpose of it to some people, while it was obvious from his voice that those things are of no use.
Because he had no cheque on him, the shop assistant couldn't return him money, no matter how hard did he try to persuade her, she offered him to change it for something else from that shop instead. So he decided to take a rifle, his wife was very angry at him for his decision, because they got the thing he exchanged as their anniversary present. 
I think, there was also a moment where his boss visited them, and tried to molest his wife, but I am not sure if it was from the same show. 
I watched the russian dub, so I don't know the languages the actors originally spoke, but it was most likely English. I watched that on TV, so I don't know anything about when it was actually released. I don't remember any actors that I recognized -- not that I actually even know a lot of them.

@Paulie_D Not that I remember anything of this. Sorry. I watched the russian dub on TV.

I have definitely seen this, although I'm blanking on a title right now.  Are you sure it was a movie and not an episode of a TV show, though?  I'm thinking something along the lines of Arrested Development

Found it!  It's an episode of Mad Men, specifically Season 1 Episode 7: "Red in the Face"

"Have you ever been hunting Peggy?"
Pete's slightly maniacal side seeps to the surface when he is tasked with returning a horrific $22 (about $160 in 2010!) chip 'n' dip. After seeing an old alpha-male college buddy at the store – who refers to him as "Humps" as in Pete "The Camel" Campbell" – an emasculated Campbell fails to get the money back and instead uses the store credit to buy a rifle. He then waggles it around pointing it at various people in the office before the reliably deadpan Hildy removes it. It's further evidence of Pete's erratic tendencies.
Pete obviously harbours some kind of suffocated desire to return to the wild and hunt – his short story concerned a hunter and a bear and when he talks to Peggy in vivid terms about what he'd do with his prey the description is murderously sexual: "I'd cut it open, drain it, dress and then I'd take my big hunting knife and cut this loin right out of the side," he hisses. Peggy seems aroused, rather than alarmed by his threat to get his "big hunting knife out", purring "That would be wonderful". Trudy [Pete's wife] is rather less enthralled, we see her shouting at Pete off-screen for the purchase of the "stupid toy".


Oh, one of my favorite episodes.
